# When rigging a car It rescales and rotates

Tags: python, animation, rigging, armature, transforms

I use Rigacar plugin. MacOs Ventura, Blender 3.4.1 (Steam)

At first I parent everything to the body of the car, origins to geometry and finally, apply all transformations.

However when: Add > Armature > Car (Deformation Rig)

The whole model rotates on it's side and scales from around 5 meters of length to 200 meters length of the car.

[image]

Next happens

[image]

The model is imported using SketchFab Add-On in Blender from URL:

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/80s-generic-police-car-low-poly-model-61766c1e6e1e4b2b803c174f33433a74

The lightning is not in the model and is added by myself.

Rotational Beacons are separated from the lightbar and rotate.

https://bayfiles.com/v0Icp5Y6y8/police_car_blend
**(close all pop-ups)**

**Z axis facing rig as mentioned in comment below an answer.**
Is it because of the ground not set??

https://bayfiles.com/6cacI4Ydy2/police_z_axis_blend

Comment: without your blend file and without seeing and important settings like transform values and rigging settings - we can just guess around.

Comment: You're right, I'll add right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the model you imported is entangled in a massive dump of empty objects that add some transformations to your mesh objects. When you run you Rigacar tool, everything is messed up.
The empties can be due to either how the modeler actually made the car, or from how Blender's importer interpreted the car's file. In any case, it's probably good to always get rid of these at least for the sake of having a clean file.

Beforehand, your car is not facing the -Y axis, which is Blender's front axis. So select the top level empty and rotate it of -90 degrees on the Z axis by pressing <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>-90</kbd><kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>.

Then, let's select only the mesh objects using the menu Select > Select All By Type > Mesh:

[image: select by type]

Then clear it off of its parents by pressing <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > Clear Parents Keep Transformations:

[image: clear parents]

Then I personally like to just move that into a new collection with a nice name by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> > New Collection:

[image: move collection]

You can delete all the other objects you don't want at this point.

Finally, apply all transforms, and you can add your rig.

Comment: A very nice answer, I will try and let you know.

Comment: Yep it's amazing, Thanks, only thing left is that it now when rigged rotates facing Z axis but all the bones are correct and the wheels are rigged as well. Still not sure what causes that Z axis facing.

Comment: That sounds weird... could you upload a file with that Z facing version?

Comment: you have the link added above now

Comment: It looks like you haven't applied the mesh objects transforms to begin with. Always do that before rigging. If your car gets rotated when adding the rig, see the rig's manual or follow a tutorial on how to use this rig.

Answer (score -1):

maybe u scaled the rig or the origin is not in the right position